# Wrapping Methods with a Thunk in Scala

Tags: scala

I have several methods in my class, each taking in different parameters and returning different parameters. For each of those methods, I want to wrap them in a common piece of code that would do some time logging. For example., when the method starts, it logs the start time and when it ends, it logs the end time and so on.

I have this method implemented:

```
def withTimerMetrics(fn: => _) = {
    Try(AppMetrics.timer.time()).map(context => {
      fn
      context.close()
    })
  }
```

Where the fn is one of the method that is implemented in my class.

Obviously, I get an unbound wildcard error. Is there a way I could do this? I do not want to use Scala macros for this. Any other ideas?

Comment: What exactly is `AppMetrics`, and why does it's `timer.time()` output something you call a closeable `context` in the next `map`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Some kind of decorator (wrapper) for your functions to log the time before and after? You can replace `_` by `AnyRef` so you will capture all functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong method signature. Try this:

```
def withTimerMetrics[T](fn: => T) = {
  Try(AppMetrics.timer.time()).map(context => {
    fn
    context.close()
  })
}
```

Not sure, why you wrap `time()` in `Try` (is it codahale metrics?), because now your function cannot be timed without changing output. I would say it should be somehow so:

```
def withTimerMetrics[T](fn: => T): T = {
  val c = AppMetrics.timer.time()
  try {
    fn
  } finally {
    context.close()
  }
}
```

So you can measure execution time without changing in your application logic.